# How to write a function in the following form f[a_, b_, c_,...] so that it is flexible with respect to the number of arguments?

Tags: list-manipulation, calculus-and-analysis, functions, numerical-integration, function-construction

@lericr have written under several of my questions that the way I try to modernize the code could be made much simpler. Below is the original part of the code. The remaining parts have similar designs, so if what I would like to get can be simplified, then this can be applied to other parts.

The goal I would like to achieve is to have the function `EER[a1_, b1_, qa_, qb_, c11_, c12_, c13_,..., c21_, c22_, c23_,...]` that depends on an arbitrary number of arguments of this type `cij`. The number of variables `cij` depends on the `imax` and `jmax`.

The function `EER` is the sum of the `Kxx` and `Pxx` each of which depends on variables `a1, b1, qa, qb, c11, c12, c13,..., c21, c22, c23,...`. I managed to present the function `Kxx` in such a way that it is flexible in relation to the number of variables (that is, when changing `imax` and `jmax`, a specific value of this function can be easily obtained by substituting the numerical values of all variables). But I can't do the same procedure with the function `Pxx`.

Once again, briefly goal: to make the function `Pxx[a1_, b1_, qa_, qb_, c11_, c12_, c13_,..., c21_, c22_, c23_,...]` universal in relation to the number of variables, and also, if possible, to reasonably simplify the code.

The code is written for `imax=1` and `jmax=2`. If you change them to `imax=2` and `jmax=3` for example, you can see that the function `Kxx` is flexible and you can immediately get its values (in:`Kxx[1.22, 0.44, 1.40, 1.81, 1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1]` out: `281.248`), but this is not done with the function `Pxx` (in:`Pxx[1.22, 0.44, 1.40, 1.81, 1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1]` out: `Pxx[1.22, 0.44, 1.4, 1.81, 1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1]`).

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
imax = 1; jmax = 2;

Psi[r_, z_, i_, j_] := Exp[-b[j]*z^2]*Exp[-a[i]*r^2];

(*variables cij*)
c[i_, j_] := Symbol["c" <> ToString[i] <> ToString[j]]
var = Join[{a1, b1, qa, qb}, 
   Flatten[Table[c[i, j], {i, 1, imax}, {j, 1, jmax}]]];
var1 = Pattern[#, Blank[]] & /@ var;

(*a[i] and b[i] are geometric progressions*)
a[1] = a1;
b[1] = b1;
Do[a[i] = a[i - 1] qa, {i, 2, imax}];
Do[b[j] = b[j - 1] qb, {j, 2, jmax}];

Kk = FullSimplify[
   Psi[r, z, i2, j2] *
    Laplacian[Psi[r, z, i1, j1] , {r, \[Theta], z}, "Cylindrical"]];
Kk1 = Integrate[Kk r, {r, 0, \[Infinity]}, {z, -Infinity, Infinity}, 
   Assumptions -> {a[i1] > 0, b[i1] > 0, a[i2] > 0, b[i2] > 0, 
     a[j1] > 0, b[j1] > 0, a[j2] > 0, b[j2] > 0}];
Kx = -1/2 2 Pi Sum[
    c[i1, j1] c[i2, j2] Kk1, {i1, 1, imax}, {i2, 1, imax}, {j1, 1, 
     jmax}, {j2, 1, jmax}];
Kxx[Sequence @@ var1] = Kx;

VB1[r_, z_] := -(1/(2*Sqrt[r^2 + z^2]))*Exp[-Sqrt[r^2 + z^2]*1/2];
Px1[a10_, b10_, qa0_, qb0_, i1_, j1_, i2_, j2_] := 
  Block[{a1 = a10, b1 = b10, qa = qa0, qb = qb0}, 
   NIntegrate[
    Psi[r, z, i2, j2]*VB1[r, z]*Psi[r, z, i1, j1]*r, {r, 
     0, \[Infinity]}, {z, -Infinity, Infinity}]];
Pxx[a10_, b10_, qa0_, qb0_, c111_, c121_] := 
  Block[{c11 = c111, c12 = c121}, 
   2 Pi Sum[
     c[i1, j1] c[i2, j2] Px1[a10, b10, qa0, qb0, i1, j1, i2, j2], {i1,
       1, imax}, {i2, 1, imax}, {j1, 1, jmax}, {j2, 1, jmax}]];

With[{var = var}, 
  EER[Sequence @@ var1] := 
   N[Kxx[Sequence @@ var] + Pxx[Sequence @@ var]]];

(*imax=1, jmax=2*)
(*Kxx[1.22,0.44,1.40,1.81,1,2]*)
(*27.549720475849007` *)
(*Pxx[1.22,0.44,1.40,1.81,1,2]*)
(*-10.388782043150181` *)

(*imax=2, jmax=3*)
(*Kxx[1.22,0.44,1.40,1.81,1,2,1,3,2,1]*)
(*281.2480800909348` *)
(*Pxx[1.22,0.44,1.40,1.81,1,2,1,3,2,1]*)
(*Pxx[1.22`,0.44`,1.4`,1.81`,1,2,1,3,2,1]*)

(*imax=1, jmax=2*)
(*EER[1.22,0.44,1.40,1.81,1,2]*)
(*17.160938432698828` *)

(*imax=2, jmax=3*)
(*EER[1.22,0.44,1.40,1.81,1,2,1,3,2,1]*)
(*EER[1.22`,0.44`,1.4`,1.81`,1,2,1,3,2,1]*)
```

Comment: Can you not simply pass a list as in `myFun[varList_List]` and then process the list items in the body of the function?

Comment: @josh, could you demonstrate this with an example, because it is not very clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, this will be long and involved. I'm basing this as much as I can on your code so that you don't have to try to translate too much. But I've only gotten halfway to your final objective. I hope you can follow this pattern to get the rest of the way (ask further questions if you can't). There are many other improvements we could make, but I wanted to stay focused as much as possible on how to write an extensible function.

Our first objective is to rewrite this:

```
Kxx[Sequence @@ var1] = Kx
```

I'm deferring tackling the `Pxx` and `EER` and so forth.

After inspecting your `var1`, we see that has four arguments at the front and then a variable number of arguments after that. But those variable arguments can always be made with a `Table` and iteration. That means they're really just a matrix. So, let's try that:

```
Kxx[a1_, b1_, qa_, qb_, c_List?MatrixQ] := Kx
```

Note the `:=`. That suspends evaluation until we need it. Now let's plug in your `Kx`:

```
Kxx[a1_, b1_, qa_, qb_, c_List?MatrixQ] :=
  -1/2 2 Pi Sum[
    c[[i1, j1]] c[[i2, j2]] Kk1,
    {i1, 1, imax}, {i2, 1, imax}, {j1, 1, jmax}, {j2, 1, jmax}]
```

Notice I changed `[]` to `[[]]`, because now we're accessing a matrix. Now consider that `imax` and `jmax` can be derived from `c`. Let's use that fact:

```
Kxx[a1_, b1_, qa_, qb_, c_List?MatrixQ] :=
  With[
    {dims = Dimensions[c]},
    -1/2 2 Pi Sum[
      c[[i1, j1]] c[[i2, j2]] Kk1,
      {i1, 1, dims[[1]]}, {i2, 1, dims[[1]]}, {j1, 1, dims[[2]]}, {j2, 1, dims[[2]]}]]
```

Time to plug in your `Kk1`, but first let's inspect it on its own:

```
Integrate[Kk r, 
  {r, 0, \[Infinity]}, {z, -Infinity, Infinity},
  Assumptions -> {a[i1] > 0, b[i1] > 0, a[i2] > 0, b[i2] > 0, a[j1] > 0, b[j1] > 0, a[j2] > 0, b[j2] > 0}]
```

We need definitions for `a` and `b`. Your definitions look like this:

```
a[1] = a1;
b[1] = b1;
Do[a[i] = a[i - 1] qa, {i, 2, imax}];
Do[b[j] = b[j - 1] qb, {j, 2, jmax}];
```

There is a problem here and an opportunity. The problem is that these definitions refer to `a1`, `qa`, etc. But as you see above we're passing in those arguments to `Kxx`, so we need to feed them to `a` and `b`. The opportunity is that `a` and `b` are simple functions, so we don't need to use a loop to pre-define values for them. In fact, they're the same function. As you noted, they are geometric sequences. So, let's do this:

```
geoseq[init_, r_, n_Integer?Positive] := init*r^(n - 1)
```

Let's plug this into our `Kxx`, but let's keep it slightly simpler by redefining `a` and `b` locally:

```
Kxx[a1_, b1_, qa_, qb_, c_List?MatrixQ] :=
  With[
    {dims = Dimensions[c],
     a = geoseq[a1, qa, #] &,
     b = geoseq[b1, qb, #] &},
    -1/2 2 Pi Sum[
      c[[i1, j1]] c[[i2, j2]] Integrate[Kk r, {r, 0, Infinity}, {z, -Infinity, Infinity}, 
        Assumptions -> {a[i1] > 0, b[i1] > 0, a[i2] > 0, b[i2] > 0, a[j1] > 0, b[j1] > 0, a[j2] > 0, b[j2] > 0}],
      {i1, 1, dims[[1]]}, {i2, 1, dims[[1]]}, {j1, 1, dims[[2]]}, {j2, 1, dims[[2]]}]]
```

Okay, now for `Kk`. It looks like this:

```
FullSimplify[Psi[r, z, i2, j2]*Laplacian[Psi[r, z, i1, j1], {r, \[Theta], z}, "Cylindrical"]]
```

So, we need `Psi`. Your `Psi` depended on `a` and `b`. But we've replaced those with `geoseq`. And now this should be déjà vu... we need to add arguments:

```
Psi[a1_, b1_, qa_, qb_, r_, z_, i_, j_] := Exp[-geoseq[b1, qb, j]*z^2]*Exp[-geoseq[a1, qa, i]*r^2]
```

Okay, putting it all together, and hoping I can do that without a copy-paste error:

```
Kxx[a1_, b1_, qa_, qb_, c_List?MatrixQ] :=
  With[
    {dims = Dimensions[c],
     a = geoseq[a1, qa, #] &,
     b = geoseq[b1, qb, #] &},
    -1/2 2 Pi 
    Sum[
      c[[i1, j1]] c[[i2, j2]] 
      Integrate[
        FullSimplify[
          Psi[a1, b1, qa, qb, r, z, i2, j2]*
          Laplacian[
            Psi[a1, b1, qa, qb, r, z, i1, j1], {r, \[Theta], z}, "Cylindrical"]] r, 
        {r, 0, Infinity}, {z, -Infinity, Infinity}, 
        Assumptions -> {a[i1] > 0, b[i1] > 0, a[i2] > 0, b[i2] > 0, a[j1] > 0, b[j1] > 0, a[j2] > 0, b[j2] > 0}],
      {i1, 1, dims[[1]]}, {i2, 1, dims[[1]]}, {j1, 1, dims[[2]]}, {j2, 1, dims[[2]]}]]
```

Let's take it for a spin:

```
Kxx[1.22, 0.44, 1.40, 1.81, {{1, 2}}]
(* 27.5497 *)
```

Notice the last argument is a matrix, we needed to reformulate from what you had. Let's try another:

```
Kxx[1.22, 0.44, 1.40, 1.81, {{1, 2, 1}, {3, 2, 1}}]
(* 281.248 *)
```

At this point there are lots of opportunities for clean up and maybe some performance improvement, but I'm going to stop there for now.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed explanation! Your description is very helpful, I was able to implement the code for the Pxx similar to how you implemented it for the Kxx

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example using a Module construct:

```
 myFun[varList_List] := Module[{i, j, varLen},
      varLen = Length@varList;
      Print["Total variables: ", varLen];
      Print["List of variables: ", varList];
      If[varLen > 1,
       Print["Last variable value: ", varList[[-1]]];
       ];
      ]
    
   myFun[{1, 2, 3, 4}]

(* Total variables: 4
   List of variables: {1,2,3,4}
   Last variable value: 4 *)
```

Comment: Thanks, but not very clear. Do I understand correctly that I need to enumerate the variables in the form of a list in this line of the code in the brackets `{ }` of the `Module`?`Pxx[a10_, b10_, qa0_, qb0_, c111_, c121_] := 
 Module[{}, PxB1[a10, b10, qa0, qb0] /. {c11 -> c111, c12 -> c121}]`

Comment: No.  the variable names in the brackets are only local variables to the function.  I didn't need the i and j and saved the number of variables in the local variable `varLen`.  In your case, I would pass the list `{a10,b10,qa0,qb0,c11,c121}` to the function.  Then the external variable `a10` becomes the local variable `varList[[1]]`, `b10` becomes the local variable `varList[[2]]` and so on.

Comment: Thanks! I tried to follow your description but it doesn't work. Could you please fix the code. Below in the answer are the lines that need to be added to the main body of the code.

Answer (score 2):

Following josh's answer:

```
c1[i_, j_] := Symbol["c" <> ToString[i] <> ToString[j] <> "1"]
varc1 = Join[{a1, b1, qa, qb}, 
   Flatten[Table[c1[i, j], {i, 1, imax}, {j, 1, jmax}]]];
varc11 = Pattern[#, Blank[]] & /@ var;
FF = Table[c[i, j] -> c1[i, j], {i, 1, imax}, {j, 1, jmax}]

Pxx[Sequence @@ varc11] := 
 Module[{Sequence @@ varc1}, PxB1[a10, b10, qa0, qb0] /. FF]

(*Pxx[1.22, 0.44, 1.40, 1.81, 1, 2]*)

(*Module[{Sequence @@ varc1}, PxB1[a10, b10, qa0, qb0] /. FF]*)
```